# AWS Aurora auto scaling group db shutdown causing mysql server gone away issue

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, magento-1.9, amazon-aurora

I'm using AWS Aurora and auto-scaling groups to add/remove database slaves based on CPU.  Several times a day, I get "General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away".  I've narrowed this issue down to the fact that when a database is removed from the auto scaling group, this exception is thrown.  I'm using the read-only cluster endpoint in my local.xml file as the core-read option.

Any ideas on how to fix this so that the connection automatically tries the reconnect once it's determined the database is no longer there?

I'm using Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: If you can post your SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; and SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; and the 200 lines each side of the time of the event from your error log, please - someone will try to assist.

Comment: @WilsonHauck this is a client-side issue.  The server --  a replica -- *has* gone away, deliberately, due to scale-in, but the client isn't reconnecting when the connection to the retired replica is lost. The read replicas in an Aurora cluster are load balanced using round robin DNS with very short TTLs, so a reconnection attempt to the same hostname would be expected to succeed... but the client side apparently isn't trying to do that.

Comment: @user2966697 You will find there are timing tolerances involved with your AWS Aurora connected to your auto-scaling groups and possibly other factors to be considered once your data is visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's my current solution.  I made a copy of lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php and created a new file app/code/local/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php.

I modified the query function as such.

change:

`$result = parent::query($sql, $bind);`

to:

```
$tries = 0;
do {
    $retry = false;
    try {
        $result = parent::query($sql, $bind);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Check to reconnect
        if($tries < 3 && stristr($e->getMessage(), '2006 MySQL server has gone away')) {
            $retry = true;
            $tries++;
            $this->_connection = null;  // Kill the current connection to the scaled out db
            $this->_connect(); // Reconnect to an available db
        } else {
            throw $e;
        }
    }
} while ($retry);
```

Comment: I've implemented this solution and I'm still get the dreaded '2006 MySQL server has gone away' exceptions when the db servers downscale.  Are you still having luck with this solution?